# Pandas DataFrame from a list of strings and n-th order tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am dealing with data that can contain stings, tuples of strings, tuples of tuples of strings, etc., e.g.

```
values = ['a0'] + [('b0', 'b1')] + [(('c0', 'c1'), ('c2', 'c3'))]
```

and I need to construct a dataframe from these values that has as many columns as the maximum number of strings amongst all list elements, i.e. 4 for the above example, with `None` in those locations where there are less than this maximum, e.g.

[image]

The `pd.DataFrame` constructor behaves differently depending on the order of elements in the list.

For example, `pd.DataFrame(['a0'] + [('b0','b1')])` results in

[image]

while `pd.DataFrame( [('b0','b1')] + ['a0'])` produces

[image]

The desired output, in this case, is

[image]

In general, a tuple might contain elements of mixed order, e.g.
`[('d0', ('d1', ('d2', 'd3')))]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections.abc import Iterable

# flatten function adapted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/4145280
def flatten(xs):
    if isinstance(xs, (str, bytes)):
        yield xs
    else:
        for x in xs:
            if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, (str, bytes)):
                yield from flatten(x)
            else:
                yield x


pd.DataFrame([flatten(x) for x in values])
```

Output:

```
    0     1     2     3
0  a0  None  None  None
1  b0    b1  None  None
2  c0    c1    c2    c3
```

Comment: Almost identical idea, even the helper function name.

Comment: @QuangHoang it's almost like, your answer is redundant :P

Answer (score 1):

You want something recursive, not just reduce:

```
def flatten(data, to_join=[]) -> list:
    # base line for recursive 
    if isinstance(data, str):
        to_join.append(data)
        return to_join
    
    # recursive through the data list
    for item in data:
        flatten(item, to_join)
    
    return to_join

flatten_df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(lambda x: flatten(x,[]), values)))
```

Output:

```
    0     1     2     3
0  a0  None  None  None
1  b0    b1  None  None
2  c0    c1    c2    c3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([np.array(x).flatten()]) for x in values])
```

Output:

```
    0    1    2    3
0  a0  NaN  NaN  NaN
0  b0   b1  NaN  NaN
0  c0   c1   c2   c3
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the references provided in the answers, I have found a 'one-liner' solution

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame([list(pd.core.common.flatten(v)) if isinstance(v, tuple) else [v] for v in values])
```